# How to group date object by hour/6 hours /day/week/month/year in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I Have 10 years of records. so API will return the array I need to group the array based on date time stamp. A user can choose a grouping option as

- hour
- 6 hours(per day)
- day
- week
- month
- year

**data example**

```
[{
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.18809978382007495
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.42347719862654404
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.365386421616013
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.49364744650351033
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.31133576985952016
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.5509062071104307
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.5556739085429424
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.6668348570127745
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.4908101365372941
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.6042127351503115
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.3725497529313371
}, {
  "x": "2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z",
  "y": 0.29687095332790064
}, {
  "x": "2018-02-07T11:19:19.034Z",
  "y": 0
}]
```

Is there any generic solutions to get grouping by hour/day/week/month/year

**Example output what I want.**

**for hour**

```
{
 "OCT 2th 2012 6AM": [
    "2012-10-02 06:00:00",
    "2012-10-10 06:03:51"
  ],
  "NOV 11th 2012 AM": [
    "2012-11-11 09:07:21",
    "2012-11-10 09:03:51"
  ],
  "OCT 6th 2013 2PM": [
    "2013-10-07 02:07:02"
  ],
}
```

**for every 6 hour**

```
{
 "OCT 6th 2012 first 6 hours": [
    "2012-10-11 06:00:00",
  ],
 "OCT 6th 2012 second 6 hours": [
    "2012-10-10 06:03:51"
  ],
  "NOV 6th 2012 AM": [
    "2012-11-11 09:07:21",
    "2012-111-10 09:03:51"
  ],
  "OCT 6th 2013 2PM": [
    "2013-10-07 02:07:02"
  ],
}
```

***for day***

```
{
 "OCT 2th 2012": [
    "2012-10-2 06:00:00",
  ],
 "OCT 10th  2012": [
    "2012-10-10 06:03:51"
  ],
  "NOV 11th 2012": [
    "2012-11-11 09:07:21",
    "2012-11-10 09:03:51"
  ],
  "OCT 7th 2013": [
    "2013-10-07 02:07:02"
  ],
}
```

**.for week**

```
{
 "OCT 2012 week number": [
    "2012-10-2 06:00:00",
  ],
 "OCT 2012 week number": [
    "2012-10-10 06:03:51"
  ],

}
```

**for month**

```
{
 "OCT 2012 ": [
    "2012-10-2 06:00:00",
  ],
 "NOV 2012": [
    "2012-11-10 06:03:51"
  ],

}
```

Comment: can you please provide sample output what you are expected if possible.

Comment: Do you want to group hour in day and day in week and month in year like nested grouping? So something like `{2009:{Jan:{2:21:{8:[{item}]}}}}`

Comment: If you don't need nested groups then lodash groupBy takes a function as second argument: `_.groupBy(data,item=>new Date(item.x).getFullYear())` will group by year. You can make it dynamic with: `const currentGroup='year';const groups = {year:item=>new Date(item.x).getFullYear()};_.groupBy(data,groups[currentGroup])`

Comment: @HMR. I have updated my question please check

Comment: What is it you need to know, how to write the functions that will return the right key from a date or what way to code a general group method?

Comment: @vinodsesetti .I have updated the  expected result sample .please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it the following way maybe?

```js
const data = [{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.18809978382007495},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.42347719862654404},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.365386421616013},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.49364744650351033},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.31133576985952016},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.5509062071104307},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.5556739085429424},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.6668348570127745},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.4908101365372941},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.6042127351503115},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.3725497529313371},{"x":"2019-02-05T14:28:45.540Z","y":0.29687095332790064},{"x":"2018-02-07T11:19:19.034Z","y":0}];

const groups = (() => {
    const byDay = (item) => moment(item.x).format('MMM DD YYYY'),
        forHour = (item) => byDay(item) + ' ' + moment(item.x).format('hh a'),
        by6Hour = (item) => {
            const m = moment(item.x);
            return byDay(item) + ' ' + ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'][Number(m.format('k')) % 6] + ' 6 hours';
        },
        forMonth = (item) => moment(item.x).format('MMM YYYY'),
        forWeek = (item) => forMonth(item) + ' ' + moment(item.x).format('ww');
    return {
        byDay,
        forHour,
        by6Hour,
        forMonth,
        forWeek,
    };
})();

const currentGroup = 'forWeek';
console.log(_.groupBy(data, groups[currentGroup]));
```

```html
<script src="https://lodash.com/vendor/cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/static/js/global.js"></script>
```